# Formatting javascript call within a datalist for a textbox

Tags: asp.net, datalist

Have a DataList on a form with two TextBox controls.  Im trying to format a javascript expression on each Textbox control that will pass the controlid of both it and the corresponding control.

In each javascript expression, I need to pass the value of EACH of the two textbox controls if possible.  The syntax Im using isnt quite right, what am I missing?

```
    (1)
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTimeFrameFrom"  style="width:50px;font-size:x-small;" onblur='javascript:updateTimeFrame(<%# String.Format("{0},{1}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TimeFrameFrom"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TimeFrameTo"))%>);'  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TimeFrameFrom")%>'></asp:TextBox>

(2)
<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="txtTimeFrameTo" onblur='javascript:updateTimeFrame(<%# String.Format("{0},{1}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TimeFrameFrom"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TimeFrameTo"))%>);'  style="width:50px;font-size:x-small;"  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TimeFrameTo")%>'></asp:TextBox>
```

**[update 1** - doesnt work]
Updating the javascript call with single quotes not working either

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTimeFrameFrom"  style="width:50px;font-size:x-small;" onblur="javascript:updateTimeFrame(<%# String.Format("'{0}','{1}'", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TimeFrameFrom"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TimeFrameTo"))%>);"  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TimeFrameFrom")%>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I  think you are missing quotes here `String.Format("{0},{1}`... because the output should be `javascript:updateTimeFrame('foo', 'bar')`

Comment: That dont seem to work either.  See update1 above

Comment: Could you share the how the element is being rendered?

Comment: Thats the problem, its not being rendered because of a page parser error "Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed."

Comment: You have to databind the entire attribute `onblur='<%# .... %>'